# Print images in body field content to node template file

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

In my node-page.tpl.php I print:

`<?php print $node->content['body']['#value']; ?>`

However, it doesn't display all body content, it does display all text entered, I use TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor to insert inline images.

Visually, editing the node, the images appear in the editor, so I wrote text before and after the image disabling the rich-text editor, and the text before and after the image appears.

Viewing the source there's no <img> tags at all.

The images are uploaded to /sites/default/files/

How can I print the images?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php print $content; ?>
```